# Android onSearchRequested() help, passing search query back to map activity

Tags: android, search, android-activity, dictionary

I have a Map activity in a fairly complex layout. As such, I can't simple search using the map's search function in that activity without making a bad window (and crashing the app, I would need onSearchRequested to use a different context, but it doesn't accept parameters.)

What I have done is made another transparent popup activity above the map activity which immediately calls `onSearchRequested()` during `onCreate()`

the thing is that when I type in something and click search, nothing happens. The search bar just clears itself but stays on screen as if prompting me to search for something again. I dont know what happens to this search query but I need it passed to my MapActivity.

I was considering doing `startActivityforResult` and passing a result back from the search popup activity, but I still have the dilemma of not knowing how to store the result and making search go away after clicking search

This class loads up a search box, thats all. It also has a transparent imageview in the space between the search box and keyboard. If a user clicks there, the activity is finished()

```
public class PseudoMapSearchActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pseudomapsearch);

    onSearchRequested();

    findViewById(R.id.blankness).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }

    });

    final SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(this.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    searchManager.setOnCancelListener(new SearchManager.OnCancelListener() {
          public void onCancel() {
              searchManager.setOnCancelListener(null);
              searchManager.stopSearch();
              finish();
          }
      });

    searchManager.setOnDismissListener(new SearchManager.OnDismissListener() {
          public void onDismiss() {
              searchManager.setOnCancelListener(null);
              searchManager.stopSearch();
              finish();
          }
      });

    //searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getCallingActivity());

    //searchManager.triggerSearch(query, launchActivity, appSearchData)
```

}

what `searchManager` function should I call to get the user typed and selected search query out of it

```
    <activity android:name=".PseudoMapSearchActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".PseudoMapSearchActivity" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

Since the Pseudomapsearch popup activity won't be doing the actual searching, and my activity with the map will be doing all the actual processing of this location data, should I then change the manifest somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store your result from an `startActivityForResult` in an Android SharedPreferences object. SharedPreferences are awesome, and can be gotten from anywhere in the application, or even globally. It is a good idea to have a class to store constants for SharedPreferences in, if you don't have one. 
The documentation for SharedPreferences is great. Here is the link:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Hope this helps!

As for getting the data from the result, you need to use the method called `onActivityResult`. Then use the appropriate request code. 
The documentation for the mentioned method can be found here:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I'm familiar with SharedPreferences, I just don't know how to get the search query results into a data variable at all

Comment: Added what you are looking for!

Comment: so I was able to get the data back to the main activity, but how do I update my mapview with this string query? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100261/android-convert-uri-geo0-0q-address-to-geopoint